# I want increase my div height dynamically 20 px each time I press a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have set the min-height value in `.css` file. Now I want to increase the height of div every time I click on a button by `20 px`.

Following is my css :

```
.wizard > .content{
    min-height:300px;
}
```

Now every time I click on say a button named `"increment"` , the `min-height` of class content should increase by `20px`.

```
<div class="wizard">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="action">
    <button id="myButton" type="button">Increment</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: ...and you've tried...what?

Comment: ermm, no problem i guess!

Comment: `$('selector').on('click', function() { $('selector').css(...) })`....

Comment: you should definitely use jquery for that ...

Comment: That's not how it works haha. You try something and if you get a problem, we might help you.

Comment: I am completely new to this jquery thing , I got it anyway but thanks everyone for posting comments .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go with this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $('.wizard .content').css({ 'min-height' : '+=20px' });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hoss/xtUPC/

Answer (score 0):

use `height()` to get current height,then use `css()` to apply height

Try this

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    var lastwidth=$('.content').height();
    var final=lastwidth+20
    $('.content').css('min-height',final+'px') 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/666gS/)

Comment: could be shortened to this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/666gS/1/).

Comment: @Mr_Green OP is new to jQuery thats why i answered lik so

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this one by using the .css property in Jquery

```
$('#myButton').on("click",function(){
        var height=$('.content').height();
        var newheight = height+20;
        $('.content').css('min-height',newheight+'px') 
    });
```

[JQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tspe7/1/)

```
  $( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(".content" ).css( "height", "+=200" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the precise spec in the question:

```
$( '#myButton' ).on( 'click', function() {

    var contentEl = $( '.wizard > .content' );
    var currentValue = parseInt( contentEl.css( 'min-height' ) );

    contentEl.css({
        'min-height': currentValue + 20 + 'px'
    });

});
```